# Access web control from class file in asp.net 4

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing a simple page (Default.aspx), where is a DropDownList (id **colors**) control. It is easy to populate it with items in PageLoad method.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        colors.Items.Add("red");
    }
}   etc. ....
```

However, is it possible to fill the **colors** control from external class file (I mean some class file located in AppCode folder).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.  For example, if you just want to create some generic utility method to bind a `IEnumerable<T>` of values to a `DropDownList`, you'd pass both of those object as arguments to the method:

```
public static void BindDropDownControl<T>(DropDownList dropDown, IEnumerable<T> listValues)
{
    // logic to bind the values to the DropDownList
}
```

What makes this work is the fact that classes like `DropDownList` are [reference types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_type).  This means that the instance of `dropDown` in the method is not a copy of the one form the page, but is instead the same one from the page.  So modifications made to it in this method will be applicable to the `DropDownList` on the page itself.

So to call it from the page, you'd do something like:

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    HttpUtils.BindDropDownControl(colors, colorValues);
}
```

Where `colorValues` is some list of values to bind to the list.  (And `HttpUtils` is the name of the class containing the above method, but you can name it whatever you want.)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a custom dropdown server control that is prepopulated with the color options. Alternatively the colors could be stored in a database table abd the dropdownlist can be populated from the db. I have never tried populating a server control from another class file. In this situation i would probably go with a custom server control.

Comment: I understand your solution, but I want to have a function, which I can call whenever I need to populate some some dropdownlist with colors

Answer (score 0):

it's possible, after all it's just object references. It's important to consider encapsulation. does it matter if you bind to a dropdownlist? what about a listbox, or checkbox list, or gridview, etc. Do you want the other components having knowledge of the webserver controls? ideally no. web server controls are a UI concern, not a data/logic concern.